# different android phone screen size issue

Tags: android, android-layout, android-screen

I'm working on an app and I'm little bit stuck there in layouts (android phones, not tablets). The problem is that I've set padding between radio buttons in single layout but with different values-hdpi and values-xhdpi and I've tested my app on galaxy nexus, nexus s and galaxy s2 which works perfectly,  galaxy nexus picks from xhdpi dimen and s,s2 pick from hdpi dimen, while user faced some padding issue on motorola droid m which has resolutions of 960x546, now I don't have other android phones to check my apk on, now what am I supposed to do to not have such issue??

please help.
Thanks in advance

Comment: make a virtual device on emulator and test it.

Comment: RKN, I've just updated my adt and I'm not able to set emulator with resolutions of 960x546!!

Comment: avd manager provides me a list of screen sizes which doesn't have 960x546 devices!

Comment: you can create new devices in **device definitions** tab in `AVD`

Comment: great RKN, now how do I know what density should I choose from xxhdpi, xhdpi, hdpi, mdpi ? and what size normal, large, x-large? any formula? thanks alot

Comment: that depends on the device you select...

Comment: @rkn use 2 seconds to write a proper answer :)

Answer (score 2):

You can check your layouts on different screens by making emulators of different sizes

Windows->android sdk and avd manager->new and give ur avd type and screen resolution and on starting that avd you can set the screen size and monitor Dpi

Please see the below link to make emulators of different sizes.
http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/managing-avds.html#createavd

Comment: thanks zeeshan, I know how to check it on avd but new adt updates weren't showing custom layouts, so solved that by going in  device definitions tab, BTW updated adt has new interface.